# passing base64string to php file using ajax and post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using mobile apllication here, I am sending image encoded data to php file using post method and getting the image url from the php file. The problem here is, I am not getting proper image while am sending string using ajax. When I place the image data manually, I am able to view the image, but when sending the image data using ajax call, unable to view the image.

```
<?php
    //$image = $_POST['uploadedfile'];//not working if an ajax call is made what is the issue here

    $image ="base64 string of an image here";//working if i place base 64 string here
    $binary = base64_decode($image);

    $fileName = time() . ".jpeg";

    file_put_contents('images/' . $fileName, $binary);

    if (file_exists('images/' . $fileName)) {
        $myjson12 = "[";
        $myjson12.='{';
        $myjson12.='"Certificate":"http://domain/demo/images/'.$fileName.'"';
        $myjson12.='}';
        $myjson12.="]";
        echo "$myjson12";
    } else {
        echo 'FAILURE';
    }
?>
```

When I am accessing the file url and sending the parameter value the output is coming as url is too long: `www.domain.com/getdata.php?uploadedfile=base64stringvalue;`

here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "www.domain.com/getdata.php",
data: { "uploadedfile": c.toDataURL("image/jpeg") },
// dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {

console.log(response + "Sri");
$("#loadImg").hide();
alert("Success");

},
error: function (data) {
$("#loadImg").hide();
alert("Connection Failed");

}
});
```

Comment: Please show the ajax call. Also, is the ajax request sent from the same domain as the php script is on?

Comment: Before anyone can really answer this you will need to place in your question, 1. the JavaScript that is posting the data, and 2. a `print_r` of the `$_POST['uploadedfile']` received.

Comment: Just on a small side note: You **never** want to build JSON by yourself, e.g. scrumble together a valid JSON string. The potential for error is just too big. Instead, use arrays, and turn that into JSON at the end using `json_encode()` which guarantees a valid result.

Comment: Is the ajax call you show taken directly from your code? Cause it have double `.php` in the url property.
The 'url is too long' issue indicates that you are doing a `GET` request, not a `POST` request tho.

Comment: its editing mistake..we have only filename.php...the value which and getting from the ajax and the value am echoing in php file both are same values but image is not coming properly

Comment: Adding to @Flosi comment. When you do send `json` as response, its also a good idea to do it when there is an error. The js code should always be able to expect the response to be the same, wether its a error or success response.

Comment: When you say 'coming properly', do you get any data at all? Or part of the data? Or the whole data but its messed up?

Comment: am getting data...as am working on both ajax call and php file the sending data and receiving data are same.